# AsyncTask task continue after app jump to another activity?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

If my app is running a thread through AsyncTask, and in the mean time I jump to another activity(scene), will the thread still run in the background.  I am thinking if I press back, the thread will already finish or original scene has to repeat the thread activity?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens to running AsyncTasks when the Activity changes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085406/what-happens-to-running-asynctasks-when-the-activity-changes)

Comment: the answer is yes...I've many nightmare crash related to this behave on released app ;)

Comment: Should I cancel the task if I want to jump to another activity and let the thread runs again when I jump back to the original activity?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. AsyncTask is just a clever wrapper around a Java Executor

Answer (score 0):

**AsyncTask** is an abstract Android class which helps the Android applications to handle the Main UI thread in efficient way. AsyncTask class allows us to perform long lasting tasks/background operations and show the result on the UI thread without affecting the main thread.

**1.** AsyncTask processes are *not automatically killed by the OS*. AsyncTask processes run in the background and **is responsible for finishing it's own job in any case**. You can cancel your AsycnTask by calling cancel(true) method. This will cause subsequent calls to isCancelled() to return true. After invoking this method, onCancelled(Object) method is called instead of onPostExecute() after doInBackground() returns.

**2.** After completion of it's operation, the **background thread it's working on is stopped**. AsyncTask has an *onPostExecute()* which is called once your work is finished.  This method is called after *doInBackground()* method completes processing. Result from *doInBackground()* is passed to this method.

Answer from [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31085558/2290548)

Answer (score -1):

The lifecycle of an Async task is not bound to an Activity. Therefore if once you have started the AsyncTask, the asyncTask will continue even if you pause/stop the Activity.

Comment: Should I cancel the task if I want to jump to another activity and let the thread runs again when I jump back to the original activity? To avoid crash of the app?

Comment: It depends on the Activity. If the async task is updating the ui of an activity, and you pressed back that Activity, then there is no sense in running that AsyncTask. But suppose you start an AsyncTask which sends some userInfo from your app to the server, In this case your asyncTask is not dependent on any activity. so it can continue.