# How to handle Asyntask when Application minimizes?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have an AsyncTask for loading an image from url to an imageView. The doInBackground() loads the image from url and a method in onPostExecute() sets the image into the imageView. What would happen if user minimizes the app when the image is loading i.e., the AsyncTask's doInBackground() method hasnt finished?

Comment: it will download but not set it , do stuff in onResume to handle the scenario

Comment: you can look into this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31085406/what-happens-to-running-asynctasks-when-the-activity-changes

Comment: I am not saying activity changes, user just puts it in background by pressing menu button when image is loading

Answer (score 0):

The asynctask will continue working. Is your responsability to handle the validity of the context when coming back to UI Thread.

So, best solution, is to set a listener and unset it on destroy, verifying it's existance on onDestroy.

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    private OnProcessFinishedListener listener;

    public void setOnProcessFinishedListener(OnProcessFinishedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
        ///Your request some info and return it. This case, a String, but could be anything.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if(listener != null) {
            listener.onProcessFinished(result);
        }
    }
}
public interface OnProcessFinishedListener {
    void onProcessFishined(String result);
}
```

Now, in your activity, before calling the asynctask, call:

```
myAsyncTask.setOnProcessFinishedListener(new OnProcessFinishedListener {    
    void onProcessFishined(String result) {
        textView.setText(result);
    }
});
```

And in your onDestroy method:

```
myAsyncTask.setOnProcessFinishedListener(null);
```

There are other ways a bit more elegant than using an AsyncTask (have you tried Picasso or Glide for images?), but this is a Start.

Comment: I get that AsyncTask will continue working. What I want to understand is if our app is in background, because user pressed menu button (activity is not destroyed) will the image get set? Can the UI thread set image to imageview although our activity is not in foreground?

Comment: As far as the ImageView exists and is reachable, it will